# Wait for class method to complete in ActionScript 3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm currently creating a website with AS3 in FlashDevelop, so it's code only — no timeline stuff.

I have a class that loads images with a method that I call from my main source. I was wondering how I go about making sure that the images are loaded before executing more code **outside of the class**. I know how to do it using *Event.COMPLETE* in the image class, but I am unsure how to get the main class to wait.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatch a custom event (like `imgLoaded`) from the image loading class once all images are loaded. Listen for that event in the main class and call the remaining functions from this event listener.